# View in a function makes the other not working

Tags: solidity, remix

Sorry, new here. I look up everywhere but couldn't find an answer. Got these 2 simple functions. Can anyone explain why if i add "view " in the setUser function (first one) the other function Getuser is not working anymore

pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
contract SalaryInfo {
struct User {
uint salaryId;
string name;
string userAddress;
uint salary;
}

```
User[] public users;

function set_User(uint _id, string _name, string _address, uint _salary) public view returns(uint) {
    users.length++;
    
    users[users.length-1].salaryId = _id;
    users[users.length-1].name = _name;
    users[users.length-1].userAddress = _address;
    users[users.length-1].salary = _salary;
    
  
    return users.length;
    
}

function get_User(uint _id) public view returns(uint, string, string, uint,uint) {
    return(users[_id].salaryId, users[_id].name, users[_id].userAddress, users[_id].salary, _id);
}
```

}

Comment: Do you understand the purpose of `view`? Do you know what it is used for? I'm assuming that if you chose to add it, you must have a reason for that, and I'm wondering what that reason is. You may want to study Solidity before trying "random stuff".

Comment: Totally agree. I'm sorry. Any books or tutorial you would suggest?

Comment: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/